Why is the coding for legend on my barplot not working after update?
I updated Rstudio and suddenly none of my legends are working on my barplots. It's my first time asking for help on here, so hopefully I am providing the info needed to get answers? Coding is below. The code for the table and the barplot work fine, but when I add in the legend it says
Error in (function (s, units = "user", cex = NULL, font = NULL, vfont = NULL,  : plot.new has not been called yet

table(df1$`enc type`, df1$`National or International`)Pet

table(df1$`Age class`, df1$`National or International`)
barplot(table(df1$`Age class`, df1$`National or International`),
        main="Age Class of Kiwi",
xlab="Age Class",
ylab="Count",
beside = TRUE,
col = c("black","white","grey")

)
legend("topleft",c("Juvenille","Subadult","Adult"), fill = c("black","white","grey"))


Updates to RStudio would not change the behaviour of R in this manner. Please provide the output of dput(df1) as part of your question in order to make your issue reproducible.

What is Pet doing after the first table?

Based on your description of the problem, it's not the legend that's not working, it's the barplot command.
